# Reading/translating an attached document without downloading it

Tags: gmail, translation

Is it possible to read an attached document, written in Nepali, in Gmail, without downloading it? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

Gmail has inline [Message Translation](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/139503?hl=en)- a bar should appear at the top an email opened in a foreign language and you can select the source (Nepali in your case) and target languages (if auto-detect doesn't produce your desired combination).

If the translation bar doesn't appear you can click the *more* down arrow (next to the reply button) and select *Translate message*

Whether or not it can translate the attachment depends on the document format- if you open and *view* the document (inside of chrome) some formats should provide you this same translate options as those that exist for the messages themselves.